# Model formset refresh extra field disappears

Tags: python, django

> My current app works all fine, but when I hit save button, the page should reload but it doesn't. It saves everything, but content stays the same, until I push refresh on browser

Edit 1.

I guess I'm not quite right. The page reloads, but the empty extra form in modelformset doesn't show up. Also the form marked for delete do not disappear. But when i refresh my page after save button was pressed, everything is fine again.

How can i achieve that without adding extra pages and redirecting to them?

Here's template and views.py

```
def task1(request):
    AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author, fields=('name','body'),extra =1, can_delete=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AuthorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

        args={}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['formset'] = formset
        return render_to_response("tasks/task1.html",args)
    else:
        formset = AuthorFormSet()
    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['formset'] = formset
    return render_to_response("tasks/task1.html",args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you don't handle success/failure differently. You need to do some redirect or something:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    formset.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Thanks! Manage to do that with HttpResponseRedirect("/task1/")

Comment: You should then accept the answer (the tick)... Anyway @UasmiNasser you should avoid absolute url and instead do it dynamically: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/